# How to change the path to open a different page initially on icecast2 sever

Tags: xslt, icecast

I have configured my Icecast.xml file as below:

```
<icecast>
    <limits>
        <sources>2</sources>
    </limits>
    <authentication>
        <source-password>password</source-password>
        <relay-password>password</relay-password>
        <admin-user>password</admin-user>
        <admin-password>password</admin-password>
    </authentication>

    <hostname>localhost</hostname>
    <listen-socket>
        <port>8000</port>
    </listen-socket>
    <fileserve>1</fileserve>
    <paths>
        <logdir>./logs</logdir>
        <webroot>./web</webroot>
        <adminroot>./admin</adminroot>
        <alias source="/" dest="/status.xsl"/>
    </paths>
    <logging>
        <accesslog>access.log</accesslog>
        <errorlog>error.log</errorlog>
        <loglevel>3</loglevel> <!-- 4 Debug, 3 Info, 2 Warn, 1 Error -->
    </logging>
</icecast>
```

Whenever, I enter the url http://localhost:8000 on a browser, the icecast status page (http://localhost:8000/status.xsl) gets opened initially. I want to change this initial/start up page to get opened with someother page (say, server_status.xls) on icecast server. Please let me know where/in which file I can change the path to open different page initially on icecast server

Answer (score 0):

It's right there in your posted configuration:

```
<alias source="/" dest="/status.xsl"/>
```

Just point *dest* to a stream or different file in your *web* directory. Save config, restart Icecast.

The *alias* tag is also explained in the Icecast documentation here:
http://icecast.org/docs/icecast-2.4.1/config-file.html#path

Note that this is just meant as a status interface and not to host a website. If you need to host a website, use a real webserver.

Comment: Hi, Thanks for your input.